# Combining object files to a single file

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker

I have been using `-r` (relocatable) flag of `arm-none-eabi-ld` to combine a bunch of object files in a specific folder (using wildcard *.o). It gets one object file as I was expecting but I am having an issue.

In particular, after combining the files together I used Ghidra and loaded the assembly of the combined object file and a few individual object files that the combined file composed of. Upon inspecting the functions, I find functions from the individual object files that are having exactly same mnemonics with the (i.e there mnemonics and function size is same) functions from the combined object file and also there are some functions that having differences among the combined object file and the individual files. For example, there is a function called `HAL_FLASH_ERASE` which was having 630 bytes in the `flash.o` file while the same function was having the size of 396 in the `combined.o` file and the underline assembly instructions are different.

I had used this flag during the past and it was perfect and the functions were exactly similar and had one to one match between the combined object file with the individual object files. However, this time my directory contains large number of files in contrast to just few object files. I am thinking whether there is a possibility to linker to overwrite the different parts with the use of `-relocatble` flag. Other than this method, is there any other way that I could try to combine multiple object files without loosing the one to one mapping between them? Thanks for the time.

Comment: But... why aren't you just creating a static library? `here are some functions that having differences among` Is by chance the `HAL_FLASH_ERASE` function declared with `inline` specifier?

Comment: I needed to load one single object file to ghidra to do some analysis. If i make it an archive then ghidra extract all the individual object files from archive and make the analysis at individual level